# How can I get a file's P4-Path using its local path in C#?

Tags: c#, perforce

For example, if a file is "E:\TMP\test.txt",and its P4 path is "//root/test.txt",how can I get the P4 path in C# as I know the local path?
Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Most Perforce commands that accept a file path will accept either a depot path or a local path as the argument, and return the depot path as part of the output.

You probably want to run a command like `p4 fstat` to get information that includes (but is not limited to) the depot path, which in the C# API is wrapped by the GetFileMetadata function:

https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4api.net/p4api.net_reference/html/M_Perforce_P4_Repository_GetFileMetaData.htm